# CSV upload (convert to spreadsheet) to google drive in iOS?

Tags: ios, csv, google-drive-api, google-sheets, converters

I have generate csv file to store inside local directory path. i have tried to upload csv file to google drive, it working fine. open a csv file from google drive not showing preview in spreadsheet. so i want to upload csv file (convert csv to spreadsheet) to google drive.
How to convert this?

Thanks in Advance

Images from google drive

[image]

Example for upload csv file to drive for your reference:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *root = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Report.csv"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:root];
if(fileExists == YES)
{
        GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = nil;
        self.driveFile = [[GTLDriveFile alloc]init];

        NSData *dat = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:root]];
        uploadParameters =
        [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:dat MIMEType:@"text/csv"];

        self.driveFile.title = @"Report.csv";
        GTLQueryDrive *query = nil;
        if (self.driveFile.identifier == nil || self.driveFile.identifier.length == 0)
        {
            query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:self.driveFile
                                                uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
        }
        else
        {
            query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:self.driveFile
                                                          fileId:self.driveFile.identifier
                                                uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
        }
        UIAlertView *alert = [DrEditUtilities showLoadingMessageWithTitle:@"While data is uploading..."
                                                                 delegate:self];

        [self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                                  GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                                  NSError *error)
         {
            appDel.File_Id = updatedFile.identifier;
            [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
            if (error == nil)
            {
                self.driveFile = updatedFile;

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Feel Fix" message:@"Successfully Uploaded" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
                [alert show];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
                [DrEditUtilities showErrorMessageWithTitle:@"Unable to save file"
                                                   message:[error description]
                                                  delegate:self];
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert Convert property to fix this issue

```
    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = nil;
    self.driveFile = [[GTLDriveFile alloc]init];

    NSData *dat = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:root]];
    uploadParameters =
    [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:dat MIMEType:@"text/csv"];

    self.driveFile.title = @"Report.csv";
    GTLQueryDrive *query = nil;
    if (self.driveFile.identifier == nil || self.driveFile.identifier.length == 0)
    {
        query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:self.driveFile
                                            uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

        query.convert = YES;   // Convert file format to spread sheet

    }
    else
    {
        query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:self.driveFile
                                                      fileId:self.driveFile.identifier
                                            uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [DrEditUtilities showLoadingMessageWithTitle:@"While data is uploading..."
                                                             delegate:self];

    [self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                              GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                              NSError *error)
     {
        appDel.File_Id = updatedFile.identifier;
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        if (error == nil)
        {
            self.driveFile = updatedFile;

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Feel Fix" message:@"Successfully Uploaded" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
            [DrEditUtilities showErrorMessageWithTitle:@"Unable to save file"
                                               message:[error description]
                                              delegate:self];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: The Swift version does not have the convert property. So I tried query.q = "convert=YES" and also "convert=true". None of them worked. Still saving as .csv. I want to save it as a google spreadsheet or excel.

Comment: For v3 of the API `convert` no longer works. Instead specify the MIME type of the upload as `text/csv` and the MIME type of the file you want as `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`.