# Get ID folder before importing data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have followed the code from [How to automatically import data from uploaded CSV or XLS file into Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854563/how-to-automatically-import-data-from-uploaded-csv-or-xls-file-into-google-sheet/26858202), but it does not explain how to find the folder ID that the file has been uploaded to.

I need to provide a spreadsheet template for multiple users that will facilitate the identification of the folder, since I have no way of knowing for sure where each user will save the csv file. I wish to avoid mistakes identifying the destination folder.

How can I obtain the ID of the folder where the user is importing their data?

Comment: I suspect there are a few parts to this question. Are you generating the Sheets for people to populate or are you aggregating sheets provided to you from wherever in xls and csv format?

Comment: the user accesses a website with your login and save the csv file or xls in a folder of your notebook. This file must be imported into the google spreadsheet drive , which will later send this data to a centralizing spreadsheet of all this information, from multiple users . My problem with the link script is that I have no way of knowing before, where the user will save the csv or xls file.

Comment: So are you talking about knowing the location of the file on the user's hard drive or their Google drive?

Comment: I mean the location of the file on the user's hard drive. if the user install Google Drive on your PC , the folder could be the very Google Drive folder, create in the instalation of the app.