# Gmail Attachment To Google Sheets Problem

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Sorry I'm new to this but I'm trying to automatically populate a Google Sheet with data from a spreadsheet which is delivered daily to my Gmail account (primarily because I'd then like to use that as a data source for a Google Data Studio Report...).

I've looked at the following pieces of code already published on Stack Overflow:

[Simple script to import gmail csv attachment to google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692201/simple-script-to-import-gmail-csv-attachment-to-google-sheets)

[Import CSV attachment into google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484198/import-csv-attachment-into-google-sheets)

[Update Spreadsheet via Email Attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623864/update-spreadsheet-via-email-attachments)

In every case I'm getting an output in Google Sheets which opens normally but then adds non alpha numeric symbols in between the numbers in the spreadsheet - e.g.:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bpeTXotjvT2dvTXiivKLd2q6j0m2QDKgQ9CYcPqxsdE/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tzuAonz7IpYnyYXagj4YG_cNEG6zx_VWx-M17YJubUg/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UHmmFgwUP5JnFsoxkf6ZhH-a2PeR_5ZHvPv7jWCtsGU/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nOzFWhhWuRzQo2nrcaw9-rQiimobubI06TA447rAGis/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone please advise what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question and add enough code to show the issue and describe your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: the CSV attachement can be encoded in a wide variety ways. The encoding of the file needs to be entered in between the brackets of etDataAsString().

So in my case this was:

getDataAsString('UTF-16')

Without that I thin it will assume the file encoding is UTF_8 by default.