# Using .setValues with empty nested array writes 'undefined' with google script

Tags: arrays, csv, google-apps-script

I'm piecing together some Google Apps Script [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854563/how-to-automatically-import-data-from-uploaded-csv-or-xls-file-into-google-sheet) that will take a list of files and import all of them as unique sheets. It works all except for if there is a blank/empty spot in any of the .csvs then the import to sheet writes that blank value as "undefined" instead of skipping over or leaving blank.

Is there a way to have a multi-dimensional array with an empty nested array and then use

```
newsheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
```

WITHOUT the blank/empty spots in my .csv setting an undefined value? Or is there a quick cleanup I can do overtop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging solved my issue with help from k.

`Logger.log(csvData[i])` is returning

`[.....Top Products, false, null, null, One per quote line, null, Quantity, false, null, Always, null, null, null,.....]`

then when I do another for loop, `Logger.log(csvData[i][j])` shows

```
[16-11-09 07:52:25:255 EST] Top Products
[16-11-09 07:52:25:256 EST] false
[16-11-09 07:52:25:256 EST] undefined
[16-11-09 07:52:25:257 EST] undefined
[16-11-09 07:52:25:257 EST] One per quote line
[16-11-09 07:52:25:257 EST] undefined
[16-11-09 07:52:25:258 EST] Quantity
[16-11-09 07:52:25:258 EST] false
[16-11-09 07:52:25:259 EST] undefined
[16-11-09 07:52:25:259 EST] Always
[16-11-09 07:52:25:259 EST] undefined
[16-11-09 07:52:25:260 EST] undefined
[16-11-09 07:52:25:260 EST] undefined
```

The following snippet inside of the nested `for` fixed my issue.

```
    if(csvData[i][j] == null){
      csvData[i][j]= '';
    }
```

Comment: If the answer of K was useful, please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When array data is outputted to spreadsheet, the array elements with null don't display "undefined" in the cell.

When the elements in a part of CSV data is empty, the array elements translated by CSVToArray are given null. So when the array is outputted to to a spreadsheet, the elements with null become clean cells without displaying "undefined".

If it is not clean cells, following code can be used.

```
for (var i=0; i< csvData.length; i++){
  csvData[i][csvData[i].indexOf("")] = null
}
```

If my understanding is incorrect, I apologize.

Comment: So using what you said didn't work for my scenario, but it did point me in the right direction. I used to for loops `for(i....) { for(j....) { ` then logged each individual index. I found that my undefined values were null in the log. So by adding `if(csvData[i][j] == null){
          csvData[i][j]= '';
        }` that solved it!