# Access SAS table through google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sas, enterprise-guide

We use SAS to manage our data, and we have a table that updates every day.

We use Google sheets to create a dashboard.

In this regard I would like to have Google Sheets access the table directly and import all the data, instead of me manually importing the data

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How are you manually importing the data now? I didn't think google had the capability read to a SAS dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Google sheets does not allow direct import of SAS datasets, according to this page:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/40608?hl=en

However, you can run a SAS program as a batch job to export your SAS dataset to csv or one of the other supported formats, then I think you could use Google Apps Script to automate the rest of the import, as per this answer:

[How to automatically import data from uploaded CSV or XLS file into Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854563/how-to-automatically-import-data-from-uploaded-csv-or-xls-file-into-google-sheet)