# Bulk import CSV file into a single sheet in a Google Sheet file

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write a Google Sheet App script that bulk import CSV files into a single sheet in a google sheet.

Every week my server is sending me a CSV file reporting with some updated data from my database. Each CSV file has exactly the same structure, since it's the same report and only date is changing.

I automatically download all the csv in a single Folder on Google Drive
Is there a way to build a script that scans the folder, open the first CSV file fills a Google sheet with the data (and the date of the CSV report) deletes the current CSV from the folder then moves to the next CSV files.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. I'd say this is a duplicate question. There is an answer to this posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854563/how-to-automatically-import-data-from-uploaded-csv-or-xls-file-into-google-sheet

Comment: Thank you @RandyD
It seems like the question was not similar but the answer given is definitely helping me !
thanks again

Answer (score 2):

if you dont want to mess around with code, you might as well us this add-on: https://www.sheetgo.com/

Worked well for us. :)

Answer (score 0):

To scan/search for files in the drive, [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) is what you need.

> You can search for files with the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) method of the Drive
>   API. Domain administrators may also search for Team Drives in the
>   organization with the teamdrives.admin.list method.

[Open and convert Google Docs in your app](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app).

> An app registered with the **Import** option enabled in the **Drive UI
>   Integration** tab within the Drive API in the API Console can import
>   supported Google Doc formats. This means that if a user selects **Open
>   with** for a Google doc, the app can convert it to a format that the
>   app can handle. When **Open with** triggers a conversion this way,
>   Drive evaluates the MIME types an app can open (set during
>   [registration](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk#setting_mime_types_and_extensions)) and extrapolates the list of formats that the app
>   can import.

Google doc formats are listed in the documentation.

And to manipulate the sheets you will open, you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet).

> The Sheets API allows you to create sheets, delete sheets, and control
>   their properties. The examples on this page illustrate how some common
>   sheet operations can be achieved with the API.

For further info, you can refer from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file).