# Upload CSV/Excel File as Sheet via Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, file-upload, google-drive-api

I see that the Drive `Folder` class has a createFile() which takes [three arguments for name, content, and mimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(String,String,String)). Is it possible to use this as part of an upload call to have a user file uploaded and converted (to Google Docs) all in one go without having to [call the REST API directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911286/9642) with `convert=true`?

For example, here's the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  <script>
  function handler(response) {
    document.getElementById('uploader').innerHTML = "Uploaded file! " + response;
  }
  </script>

</head>
  <body>
  <div id="uploader">
  <form>
   <input type="file" name="theFile">
   <input type="button" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(handler).uploadFile(this.parentNode)" value="Upload!">
  </form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the Google Script code:

```
function uploadFile(e) {
  Logger.log("Uploading file!");
  var dfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('abcdefgh');  // replace w/ Drive FolderID
  return dfolder.createFile(e.theFile).getName();
}
```

How would I go about changing that last line to something like:

```
return dfolder.createFile(newName, e.theFile, MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
```

Something I'm trying to figure out now is simply how to get the *name* of the file being uploaded (e.g. for `newName`). And then how to go about converting whatever form `e.theFile` is in to a string. If I try this as-is now I get the error:

> Invalid argument: file.contentType at uploadFile(Code:31)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to upload CSV and Excel files using `google.script.run`.
- When the file is uploaded, you want to convert to Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to retrieve the filename of the uploaded file.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

I think that in your script, it is required to modify the Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- Value of `e.theFile` of `uploadFile(e)` is the blob. So you can retrieve the filename using `getName()`.
- You can convert the CSV and Excel format to Google Spreadsheet using Drive API. In this case, I used Drive API v2 at Advanced Google Services.
- The reason of the error of `Invalid argument: file.contentType at uploadFile` is that the mimeType of `MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS` cannot be used with `createFile()`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `uploadFile()` as follows. Before you use this script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services, and set the folder ID to `folderId`.

```
function uploadFile(e) {
  Logger.log("Uploading file!");

  // I modified below script.
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID here.
  var blob = e.theFile;
  var filename = blob.getName();
  var mimeType = blob.getContentType();
  if (mimeType == MimeType.CSV || mimeType == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || mimeType == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {
    return Drive.Files.insert({title: filename, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{id: folderId}]}, blob).title;
  }
  return "";
}
```

#### References:

- [Class Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob)
- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: insert of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, this is not what I expected but it doesn't require calling the REST API directly so I would say this answers my question.

Comment: @Neil C. Obremski Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I thought that I have to study more. Thank you, too.

Comment: Ah ... I see this _is_ calling the REST API directly. This must mean that there is no way to do what I'm asking through the Google App Script classes

Comment: I replaced the `Drive.Files.insert` call in your example w/ a call to `convertExcel2Sheets(blob, filename, mimeType, [folderId]).getName();` from https://gist.github.com/azadisaryev/ab57e95096203edc2741 (I added a mimeType parameter to the function)

Comment: @Neil C. Obremski Thank you for your additional information.