# Getting data from excel sheet to spreadsheet automatically?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, automation

I am trying to extract data from excel to google spreadsheet. I want to do it automatically. Is there an automated way available? There is an add-on called Sheetgo but it is paid is there any free one? I want this extraction to happen daily at a scheduled time. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You may find some good solutions here:
[How to automatically import data from uploaded CSV or XLS file into Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854563/how-to-automatically-import-data-from-uploaded-csv-or-xls-file-into-google-sheet)

One of the [answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169992/pukeko) to this thread even [claims to have created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56511738/3390898) a “utility for automated import of xlsx files into google spreadsheet” called [xls2sheets](https://github.com/rusq/xls2sheets) that you might find interesting.